# Can a USB-C monitor replace a docking station?

Tags: display, docking-station, usb-c

I am setting up a home office. I have a laptop, a mouse and a keyboard. I was going to buy a monitor and a docking station. However, I have discovered monitors with USB-C connection (I <del>am considering</del> ordered a [Lenovo
ThinkVision T27h-20 with USB-C](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjIiu_Ys4nrAhXkkIsKHRiuBLEQFjABegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lenovo.com%2Fgb%2Fen%2Faccessories-and-monitors%2Fmonitors%2Foffice%2FT27h-20C19270QT127inch-Monitor-HDMI%2Fp%2F61ECGAT2UK&usg=AOvVaw1CEcv1ZcZVYQ8uHjMGfsU1)) and found some hints online that such a monitor could replace a docking station; see e.g. [this picture](https://www.viewsonic.com/library/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/LB0049-2-compressed.png) in the article ["Purchasing a USB-C Monitor – What to Bear in Mind"](https://www.viewsonic.com/library/business/purchasing-usb-c-monitors/). If this is true, I would love to save the money and the space on my desk.

Can it be so simple? Can a USB-C monitor (partly) replace a docking station? Would plugging the keyboard and the mouse into the monitor and then plugging the monitor into the laptop produce a functioning setup?

**Update:** I have just tested out the setup, and it works beautifully. The keyboard and the the mouse are plugged into the monitor, and the monitor is plugged into the laptop. The monitor also charges the laptop.

Comment: It depends on what the monitor provides and what you need. Most docks provides: 1) power, 2) USB ports, 3) connections to monitors, 4) Ethernet, 5) audio. The biggest concern about T27h-20 is it doesn't seem to provide power to your laptop. Also note that your laptop may or may not support DP over USB-C.

Comment: @user3528438, thank you for your feedback! I do not expect the monitor to be entirely as versatile as a proper dock. But would you expect plugging in the keyboard and the mouse into the monitor and plugging in the monitor into the laptop to produce a functioning setup? I.e. so that the keyboard and the mouse would work as expected. Charging is not so important to me, I could use an external charging cable for the laptop if necessary. My practical concern is whether buying the dock in addition would provide any noticeable benefits for a minimalistic home office (without ethernet, audio, etc.).

Comment: @user3528438, regarding DP (display port?) over USB-C, how do I find out whether my laptop supports that? E.g. my main laptop is a ThinkPad X1 Carbon 5th gen, but I also have another, older piece: a ThinkPad T530 with an i7 processor (so that it does have USB 3.0 ports). And if I may, how did you find out T27h-20 does not provide power to the laptop? Where should I look to learn such things?

Comment: The spec sheet from the lenovo product page should tell you that. To me it sees non-minimalistic to have more than 0 cables coming out of the laptop, but it's up to you.

Comment: @user3528438, OK, thank you. A Lenovo sales representative persuaded me to buy a dock that connects to the laptop by a cable rather than one that you place the laptop on top, so there will be at least 1 cable (and then the 2nd cable for charging if the monitor does not charge the laptop). I have not made the purchase of the dock yet but have ordered the monitor already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This new breed of monitors is called "Docking Monitor".
They are intended to also act as a dock to reduce the number of cables
connected to the computer.

My understanding of the USB-C ports of your monitor is:

1. *1 x USB Type-C Gen1 (DP1.2 Alt Mode)*
   This can be connected to the computer for display on the monitor.
   If the monitor can still function as a dock when this is its only
   USB-C connection to the computer,
   then the performance as a dock will be poor because some USB-C data-paths will
   be used for the display, leaving not enough, so the dock performance might drop
   to USB 2.0 levels.
2. *1 x USB 3.1 Gen1 port (Upstream, by USB Type-C)*
   This can power a laptop and perhaps also act as the dock connection when the
   monitor is connected by HDMI/DVI/DP
   (It's unclear which of the two USB-C connection works for the dock in
   this case).
3. *4 x USB 3.1 Gen1 ports (Downstream, incl. 1 x BC)*
   These ports can be used as a 4-port dock.

I have no information about the performance of this monitor when used
as a dock. This would require testing with your own devices.

Comment: Looking at 1. and 2., would there be two cables connecting the monitor to the laptop? By the way, I just checked with a colleague who has succeeded in what I ask about. I think he used a single cable between the monitor and the laptop. (The only difference between him an me is the exact model of the monitor, but the difference is pretty small – T27h vs. P27h – and he says mine should work just as well.)

Comment: (With no guarantee,) one cable should work for this kind of monitor. Depending on the required USB performance, and on the display resolution & frequency.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is most probably yes.  As long as the connection from the laptop to the monitor supports USB data, then it will should work.

Comment: That would be great. Perhaps I should first buy the monitor and experiment with the intended setup. Only if that does not work would I have to buy the docking station.

Comment: A dock is more than a USB hub.

Comment: @user3528438, true, but what about "docking monitors" mentioned in another answer here?